# ElementCollections unique on id of parent, specified value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an instance where I'm trying to keep track of all users in a category, where the users could switch around. For instance, let's assume I have a simple Entity class as follows.

```
@Entity
public class Photo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    List<User> flaggedUsers;
    //Contains getters and setters
}
```

A single user might flag 2 photos, and thus be a part of 2 lists. Ideally, I'd like to have a unique constraint on the combination of the main id and the user. How might I accomplish this?

This code fails a unique constraint when the second user goes to flag the image, because the unique is set on the user, not the combination of user/ Photo Id.

I tried to use a @CollectionsTable, as follows, but with the error as listed

```
@Entity
public class Photo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @CollectionTable (name="photo_flagged_users", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="flaggedUsers"),uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"photo.id","flaggedUsers"}))

    List<User> flaggedUsers;
    //Contains getters and setters
}
```

In Eclipse, the @UniqueConstrants is red, with the following tool tip text:

> The value for annotation attribute CollectionTable.uniqueConstraints must be some @javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint annotation

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673118/jpa-how-to-express-a-unique-constraint-including-an-elementcollection-column help?

Comment: It's close, but the @CollectionTables doesn't seem to work as expected, at least there's something that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest keep your `Photo` and `User` entities clean of relationships and introduce an in-between layer/table to accommodate this. Say this new table is called `Photo_Users`

`Photo` <-1..many-> `Photos_Users` <-many..1-> `User`

You'll also introduce the unique key as an embedabble class:

```
@Embeddable
public class PhotosUsersEntityKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="PROPERTY_ID", nullable=false)
    private Integer    userId;

    @Column(name="BILL_ID", nullable=false)
    private Integer    photoId;

//getters+setters
}
```

and the PhotoUsersEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Photos_Users")
public class PhotosUsersEntity implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private PhotosUsersEntityKey compositePrimaryKey;

//rest
}
```

This setup will give you the flexibility you need.